# domain configuration not working properly

Tags: dns, hosting

I have purchased a domain from bigrock.in and created a free hosting account in 5gbfree.com. but i couldn't find how to add my domain to it. Domain name venneers.in. please someone help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The domain: venneers.in resolves IP address: 173.193.106.13. Looking at online DNS settings, there does not seem to be an issue with DNS configuration.

When we browse this domain it is showing blank page. You must browse site from server to check the exact error and get it fixed OR check in log files to find the exact error.